# How can i call a JQuery function outside of a JQuery class?

Tags: jquery

I have a class:

```
var BrandDrug = Class.extend({
    fun1: function() {
       $.MyFunc(); //This does not work.
    }
});


//Outside function
$.MyFunc = (function() {
   //Code
});
```

How can i call the $.MyFunc from the BrandDrug Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the "$.MyFunc" before the "BrandDrug" class and it will work.

edit: also note that you are not extending jQuery properly. See [this tutorial](http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html) (for example) on how to build proper jQuery plugins.

Comment: I was caught up fixing another bug. Thanks, it helped.